# Favorite icon VS Badge icon

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

I find the icons for badges too similar to the icon for favorite questions. I remember that this confused me when learning to find my way around the page and what the badge are.

Here is the favorite button next to a question:

[image]

Here it almost looks like Jeff Atwood has 4 favorite questions.

[image]

Why is this? Can it be changed?

Comment: They are the same icon...but sure if I find them confusing thouugh. The favorite question icon is always a star...we just happen to have a star in a circle as our badge icon. Now that I look they are almost identical to the silver badges though.